# Performance Counters - ASP.NET v4.0.30319 - Blank /Missing counter objects for system-level ASP.NET, but not application-level ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, performancecounter

Any of the counters under the ASP.NET v4.0.30319 or ASP.NET section do not have any objects to select when highlighted,

but any of the counters under the ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319 section DO have objects to select (recognize my running IIS applications)

**Things i have verified:**

- There's no Disable Performance Counter entry in the registry for ASP.NET v4.0.30319 or ASP.NET
- There's no Disable Performance Counter entry in the registry within any keys under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\
- i see that within the **Names** key for ASP.NET v4.0.30319, that there are two entries that correctly contain the PID of the currently running w3wp processes. To note there is NOT a Names key under ASP.NET, only Linkage and Performance
- i've ran the 32bit version of perfmon.exe as administrator found in this directory but it had the same result C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
- running powershell as admin and querying the related classes shows only 0 values (Both PerfRawData and PerfFormattedData)

```
__GENUS                         : 2
__CLASS                         : Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319
__SUPERCLASS                    : Win32_PerfRawData
__DYNASTY                       : CIM_StatisticalInformation
__RELPATH                       : Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319=@
__PROPERTY_COUNT                : 29
__DERIVATION                    : {Win32_PerfRawData, Win32_Perf, CIM_StatisticalInformation}
__SERVER                        : REDACTED
__NAMESPACE                     : root\cimv2
__PATH                          : \\REDACTED\root\cimv2:Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319=@
ApplicationRestarts             : 0
ApplicationsRunning             : 0
AuditFailureEventsRaised        : 0
AuditSuccessEventsRaised        : 0
Caption                         :
Description                     :
ErrorEventsRaised               : 0
Frequency_Object                : 0
Frequency_PerfTime              : 0
Frequency_Sys100NS              : 10000000
InfrastructureErrorEventsRaised : 0
Name                            :
RequestErrorEventsRaised        : 0
RequestExecutionTime            : 0
RequestsCurrent                 : 0
RequestsDisconnected            : 0
RequestsInNativeQueue           : 0
RequestsQueued                  : 0
RequestsRejected                : 0
RequestWaitTime                 : 0
StateServerSessionsAbandoned    : 0
StateServerSessionsActive       : 0
StateServerSessionsTimedOut     : 0
StateServerSessionsTotal        : 0
Timestamp_Object                : 0
Timestamp_PerfTime              : 0
Timestamp_Sys100NS              : 132514118714090000
WorkerProcessesRunning          : 0
WorkerProcessRestarts           : 0
PSComputerName                  : REDACTED
```

OS: Windows Server 2019 DataCenter
This issue resides within all of our 500+ aws instances

[image: here's a screenshot of the issue i see]

Comment: In order to monitor the performance of specific applications more conveniently, there are no objects to choose from in ASP.NET.  ASP.NET as an application development framework, is an application service provider. But ASP.net application can monitor various conditions during application operation and reflect the performance of the application.

Comment: Thank you Bruce, this insight is what i needed,

In layman's terms, he's say there won't be objects for system-level counters because their system-wide counters, the system IS the counter basically. So if you click add you'll see the data you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Bruce Zhang's comment was the answer i needed.